# How to convert a datetime string to datetime without milliseconds pyspark

Tags: date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I keep getting NULLs with every single different solution I found related to this question

```
spark.sql('select DateColumn from table')
```

yields the following value

```
2021-07-26T22:12:10.3990989Z
```

I would like to convert this string into a datetime value without milliseconds as such

```
2021-07-26 22:12:10 PM
```

How can I perform this operation either in the sql statement or outside of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`from_unixtime`**,**`unix_timestamp`** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----------------------------+
#|ts                          |
#+----------------------------+
#|2021-07-26T22:12:10.3990989Z|
#+----------------------------+

df.withColumn("ts1",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("ts"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a")).\
show(10,False)
#+----------------------------+----------------------+
#|ts                          |ts1                   |
#+----------------------------+----------------------+
#|2021-07-26T22:12:10.3990989Z|2021-07-26 22:12:10 PM|
#+----------------------------+----------------------+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
df.withColumn("ts1",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("ts"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp")).\
printSchema()
#root
# |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
# |-- ts1: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: It returns a data type of type String and not datetime tho. And if I cast to timestamp it returns NULL

Comment: @RogerSteinberg, that is not possible as I have `am/pm` at the end, Spark timestamp type only accepts `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format. if you need timestamp type then please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help -

```
    ts = '2021-07-26T22:12:10.3990989Z'
query = f"""  
    SELECT MAKE_TIMESTAMP (
      YEAR ('{ts}'),
      MONTH('{ts}'),
      DAY('{ts}'),
      MINUTE('{ts}'),
      SECOND('{ts}'),
      0
      ) as ts """
spark.sql(query).show()
```

Results -

```
+-------------------+
|                 ts|
+-------------------+
|2021-07-26 12:10:00|
+-------------------+
```

0 would be the timezone, I think running it on your machine would yield desired results.